# How to use HttpClient PostAsync() with threadpool in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the following code to post an image to a server.

```
var image= Image.FromFile(@"C:\Image.jpg");
Task<string> upload = Upload(image);
upload.Wait();

public static async Task<string> Upload(Image image)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
    {
        Host = "somewhere.net",
        Path = "/path/",
        Port = 443,
        Scheme = "https",
        Query = "process=false"
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("locale", "en_US");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("country", "US");

        var content = ConvertToHttpContent(image);
        content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

        using (var mpcontent = new MultipartFormDataContent("--myFakeDividerText--")
            {
                {content, "fakeImage", "myFakeImageName.jpg"}
            }
        )
        {
            using (
                var message = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri, mpcontent))
            {
                var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return "nothing for now";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to modify this code to run multiple threads.  I've used "ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem" before and started to modify the code to leverage it.

```
private void UseThreadPool()
{
    int minWorker, minIOC;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorker, out minIOC);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, minIOC);

    int maxWorker, maxIOC;
    ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxWorker, out maxIOC);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(4, maxIOC);

    var events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

    foreach (var image in ImageCollection)
    {
        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            arg =>
            {
                var img = Image.FromFile(image.getPath());
                Task<string> upload = Upload(img);
                upload.Wait();
                resetEvent.Set();
            });
        events.Add(resetEvent);

        if (events.Count <= 0) continue;

        foreach (ManualResetEvent e in events) e.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

The problem is that only one thread executes at a time due to the call to "upload.Wait()".  So I'm still executing each thread in sequence.  It's not clear to me how I can use PostAsync with a thread-pool.

How can I post images to a server using multiple threads by tweaking the code above?  Is HttpClient PostAsync the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'd like to modify this code to run multiple threads.

Why? The thread pool should only be used for CPU-bound work (and I/O completions, of course).

You can do concurrency just fine with `async`:

```
var tasks = ImageCollection.Select(image =>
{
  var img = Image.FromFile(image.getPath());
  return Upload(img);
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Note that I removed your `Wait`. You should avoid using `Wait` or `Result` with `async` tasks; use `await` instead. Yes, this will cause `async` to grow through you code, and you should use `async` "all the way".

Comment: +1. Using existing functionality let one write code that is easier to reason about... Also kills all the fun of manually managing/debugging events/threads/mutexes and other hard to get right pieces of code :) Side note: I'd potentially get list of paths' first (as it is synchronous and unlikely to fail operation) and than started upload (possibly with asynchronous reading of the file as it is slow I/O bound operation similar to HTTP request).

Comment: Thank-you Stephen.  This works, though I'm concerned with creating too many threads at one time which could thrash the cpu and consume all the memory.  I'm potentially processing tens of thousands of images at one time.  This code creates all the threads at once.  I could limit it in batches, say running a couple hundred at a time.  A thread pool automatically handled the number of active threads for me.  Are my concerns valid?  Is there a smooth way to limit the number of active threads processing at one time?

Comment: @TERACytE: There are no threads used in the code I posted; if this is confusing, I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post that may help. HTTP requests have built-in throttling in .NET, so if you want to limit the number of requests per server, you can just set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. If you want to limit the file reading, too (which you probably would), you can use `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: Thank-you again Stephen.  I'm considering this question answered.  I'll look in to DefaultConnectionLimit and SemaphoreSlim too.